# How to change value of an element in two dimensional array in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have created a two dimensional array and the whole 2D array is populated with 9 like this.

```
matrix = Array.new(5,(Array.new(5,9)))
```

Next I am printing the whole array

```
puts "#{matrix}" # => [[9, 9, 9, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9]]
```

Next I am assigning `1` to the `[0][0]` position.

```
matrix[0][0] = 1
```

Then I am again printing the matrix

```
puts "#{matrix}" # => [[1, 9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 9, 9, 9, 9], [1, 9, 9, 9, 9]]
```

So, here is the case! Why every row is being affected by this assignment. Shouldn't it only change the value of `[0][0]` position.
I am using `ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-linux]`.

Comment: The clue is in the output. See what `matrix.each {|a| puts a.object_id }` returns.

Comment: they all are same! got your point

Comment: `matrix = Array.new(5, Array.new(5,9))` (your extra parens are not needed) is the same as `arr = Array.new(5,9); matrix = Array.new(5, arr)`. Got it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, you are using the same array reference for every subarray. Do it like this

```
matrix = Array.new(5) { Array.new(5, 9) }
```

Comment: ya I have understood what's happening with my declaration. Your declaration worked as charm!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not creating 5 different arrays:

```
matrix = Array.new(5,(Array.new(5,9)))
```

this code is creating a new array which is then used five times. So, when you set the cell of the first array to 0, you actually set them all to 0.

To fix this, you need to create individual array, for example this way:

```
matrix = []

5.times do 
  matrix.push(Array.new(5,9))
end
```

Then the code will work the way you expect:

```
   matrix[0][0] = 5
   puts matrix #  [[5, 9, 9, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9, 9, 9]]
```

Comment: That works but the idiomatic way to create `matrix` is as given by @ursus.